# SPARQL if-then-else statement

Tags: if-statement, sparql

I am trying to create an RDF graph, in which:
if `?n1` exists then a triple of the form: `<?x ex:n "1">` will be created.
Otherwise, a triple of the form `<?x ex:n "0">` will be created.
My code is the following:

```
CONSTRUCT {?x ex:n ?result .}

WHERE { 
  ?x ex:n ?n1 .
  BIND (IF(?n1 ="    *"^^xsd:string, "0", "1") AS ?result)
}
```

However, only the triples where the value of `?n1` exists are created (`<?x ex:n "1">`).
I miss the triples of the form: `<?x ex:n "0">`.
Why does it happen?

Comment: it happens because your `WHERE` part will only be evaluated if there is such a triple `<?x ex:n "1">` - if this already doesn't match, then the `BIND` will never be evaluated

Comment: I'm not sure what you're interested in. Please share sample data and the expected result

Comment: The query seems ok. If you don't get any result for `0` it means that in your KB no `?n1` is equal to the string `"    *"` (or better, there is no `?x` such that `<?x ex:n "    *"^^xsd:string>`).

Comment: from my understanding the TO want's to get "0" or "1" (not clear about the meaning) even when there is no such triple with predicate `ex:n` - that's why I said the join will only work for existing triples with the given predicate and then BIND will not evaluated otherwise at all.

Comment: by the way, not sure about the semantics of the data here, but RDF has at least two other datatypes that would fit better to indicate presence/absence of something: `xsd:boolean` or at least use a number type like `xsd:integer` or for smaller range `xsd:byte` - though I'd go with the boolean type for sure

Comment: @horcrux 
Using "    *"^^xsd:string
I am trying to specify that if ?n1 (which is a String) does not have any value - is an empty String return ?result = "0".
Is so wrong?

Comment: this is a misunderstanding of the data model. absence of data all does not mean an "empty string". it is literally not there, see it as unbound or NULL or whatever - and this clearly isn't the same as an empty string. That why I was saying for absence you have to use an additional pattern

Comment: I'm also still not convinced by the modeling here. Why do you want to add another string literal for the same property? Should you use another property and even then with a boolean value that indicates absence or presence of a string match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"    *"^^xsd:string` will not check that your string is empty. Instead it literlly means "four spaces followed by an asterisk".

For checking that a string matches a pattern, you should use the SPARQL [`REGEX`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex) function. So you may want to use `REGEX(?n1, "^ *$")`, where `^` and `$` match respectively the begin and end of the pattern and `*` is the zero-or-more quantifier.

```
CONSTRUCT { ?x ex:n ?result . }
WHERE { 
  ?x ex:n ?n1 .
  BIND (IF(REGEX(?n1, "^ *$"), "0", "1") AS ?result)
}
```

---

**EDIT**: If you want also to retrieve values for `?x` where you dont have `<?x ex:n ?n1>` but you do have `<?id ex:p ?x>`, you can do something like this:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?x ex:n ?result . }
WHERE { 
  { ?id ex:p ?x . } UNION { ?x ex:n ?n1 . }
  BIND (IF(!BOUND(?n1) || REGEX(?n1, "^ *$"), "0", "1") AS ?result)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.
However, I still miss the triples for which ?n1 is empty since there is an RDF path:

?id ex:p ?x .
?x ex:n ?n1 .

How could I check that the path stops at <?id ex:p ?x> ?
These are the paths I'd like to create triples of the form <?x ex:n "0">

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mary I edited the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. 
However, I still miss those triples.
Is there a way to check that the path or better the property "ex:n" 
does not exist for the variable ?x   ?

Comment: @mary You cannot ask for what doesn't exist, because you would refer to a possibly infinite domain. You have always to start from *positive knowledge* and then eventually remove from it. In your case, I understood that the positive knowledge is that any `?x` must be pointed with an `ex:p` property by a certain `?id`. If there are other possible ways of reaching `?x`, you can add them in the same way above.